# ZF2: Why do I have to refresh after uploading an image?

Tags: file-upload, zend-framework2

In my ZF2 application I am uploading images using `\Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload`. This works fine except that often, after uploading the file, I have to 'refresh' my view otherwise I still see the old image.  I think it's a performance problem, and while I can think of several cumbersome ways around it, I would be surprised if there's not a 'standard' way to deal with it.

The situation is that my application has 'Company Profiles'.  If a company wants to change their logo, they view their profile and click 'change logo'.  This presents a modal form where the user uploads a new image.  When the form is submitted the image is uploaded, and there is a 302 redirect back to the company profile.

Here's how I am configuring the file upload filter:

```
$filter = new \Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload(array(
    'target' => './public/uploads/logos/' . md5($orgId . SALT),
    'overwrite' => true));
```

I am then attaching it to an InputFilter, and when I call InputFilter::getValues(), that's where it is 'renamed', (i.e. moved) from the temp directory to my uploads directory.

I am working on a high-spec desktop machine running Linux.  I can't imagine that performance is going to be any better in a production environment.

What's the best way to deal with this problem?  I could, for example, check for the existence of a file and remove it before renaming the upload, but that would diminish the purpose of having the rename upload filter in the first place.  Surely there is a better solution?

EDIT: OK, so I now think this is just the browser cache.  I have appended a random query parameter to the img src attribute and the problem has not recurred.  If I can determine conclusively that it is solved, I'll write this up as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so per the edit above, the answer was that the client was caching the image, and appending a query parameter to the img src attribute has sorted it out.  Case closed.